# How do I access the name of the Rails 3 application object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to know the name of a programmers application from within a Rails 3 engine.

Comment: do you want to get to the Application name how you created it when you did a "rails new your-application" , or just the Class name?

Answer (score 138):

**Rails <= 6.0**

`Rails.application.class.parent_name`

**Rails 6.1 and higher**

`Rails.application.class.module_parent_name`

Comment: this is the Class name, and not the name of the Application as it is checked-in

Comment: Rails.application.class.parent gives you the module constant, which you can then call to_s or name upon.

Comment: Rails.application.class.parent_name has been deprecated and replaced by Rails.application.class.module_parent_name

Answer (score 22):

The original poster asked for **the name of the rails app**, not for the class name. Those are two different things. e.g. the spelling of the rails app can be different from what  Rails expects, e.g. 'test-app' instead of 'test_app'.

It is difficult to get to the **name of the Rails App spelled the way as it was checked-in**, because that name is not preserved. Only the options for the session_store seem to contain the original string slightly modified.

**The best way to get to the name of the Rails application is:**

This will work even if your app directory was renamed, or sym-linked!

```
Rails.application.config.session_options[:key].sub(/^_/,'').sub(/_session/,'')
=> "test-app"
```

Why? Because the author of the app could have spelled it's **name** differently than Rails expects... e.g. with '-' characters instead of '_'; e.g. "test-app". From the class name you can't guarantee to get to the correct spelling.

Using this info, you could do this:

```
class << Rails.application
  def name
    Rails.application.config.session_options[:key].sub(/^_/,'').sub(/_session/,'')
  end
end

Rails.application.name
=> 'test-app'
```

or just add this to your `./config/environment.rb`:

```
APP_VERSION = '1.0.0'
APP_NAME = Rails.application.config.session_options[:key].sub(/^_/,'').sub(/_session/,'')
```

that makes these constants available on the top-level of the app.

---

**Close, but no cigar:**

This is almost correct, but it will still fail if the application directory gets renamed (e.g. during deployment to '"20121001_110512" or "latest"... then the following would break:

```
File.basename(Rails.root.to_s)
=> "test-app"
```

---

with the following two approaches you can't get to the correct spelling.. you could only guess a name:

**This is sub-optimal, and can give incorrectly spelled results:**

You can get to a derivative of the application name like this:

```
Rails.application.engine_name.gsub(/_application/,'')
=> "test_app"
```

But please note that this is not fool-proof, because somebody could have named the app 
"test-app" and you will see the result above, not the correct name with '-'.

Same thing is true if you derive it like this:

```
Rails.application.class.parent_name
=> "TestApp"
```

this is the class name, but you can't be sure how to get to the name the way the author spelled it.

Comment: I think it should be `Rails.application.class.parent_name` in the last section but I can't edit it because my change is less than 6 characters. Thanks StackOverflow.

Comment: This is the correct, Rails-y answer. I would also note that most users would want to call .humanize.titleize on this for use in a view.

Comment: It's not Rails-y if the user names their Rails app with a '-' :)
and they can shoot-themselves in the foot with it. Rails will insist there is an underscore, when there isn't. Happened to me :P

Comment: I suggest `Rails.application.engine_name.gsub(/_application$/,'')` for that one solution in case the user used '_application' somewhere in the application's name.

Answer (score 16):

In Rails 3, the application that is generated is given a module namespace matching the application name. So if your application was called "Twitter", the class of Rails.application is "Twitter::Application".

This means that you could split the string of the class name of your Rails application to get an application name like this:

```
Rails.application.class.to_s.split("::").first
```

In our example, the resulting string would be "Twitter".

Comment: Is there something similar that can be used in rails 2.3?

Comment: this is the Class name, and not the name of the Application as it is checked-in

Comment: @tilo True, except that for 97% of cases, this is good enough for most people that name their app carefully

Comment: @ScottLowe true! I just added my answer because I had a case where I needed the real app name..

Comment: @Tilo Yep... it's a good alternative. I was just being grumpy. haha!

Answer (score 5):

`Rails.application` returns your `MyApp::Application` class.

Answer (score 5):

**For Rails 6 and beyond**

`Rails.application.class.module_parent.name`

*More context:*

`Module#parent` has been renamed to `module_parent`. `parent` is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 6.1.

Answer (score 3):

For a more "humanized" version (based on the first reply you can find here) consider the following method: it will return `Test App` for your `TestApp` application.

```
def app_name
  Rails.application.class.parent_name
    .underscore
    .humanize
    .split
    .map(&:capitalize)
    .join(' ')
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Scott's answer, I put the following in my `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` file

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  helper_method :app_name
  private
    def app_name
      Rails.application.class.to_s.split("::").first
    end
```

Then in my templates I can just do `#{app_name}` wherever it's needed, which makes it much less of a hassle if you need to rename your app (which I had to do this morning).

Answer (score 0):

You can find this in the config.ru file:

```
run Dinosaur::Application
```

or in the Rakefile:

```
Dinosaur::Application.load_tasks
```

The name prior to the "::" is the app name