# How to get Rails app_name in my edge file & rake generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

I want to get app_name variable in rake task called via edge file.

cmd:

`rails new asdf_com -m http://refinerycms.com/t/edge`

and I want to get "app_name" in my generator called from [edge file](http://refinerycms.com/t/edge)

row with:

`generate "refinery:cms --fresh-installation #{ARGV.join(' ')}"`

and in [rake task](https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/blob/master/core/lib/generators/refinery/cms/cms_generator.rb):

I want to get in [this file](https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/blob/master/core/lib/generators/refinery/cms/templates/config/database.yml.mysql) the app_name to change:

`database: your_local_database`
to change to
`database: <%= app_name %>_dev`
to get "database: asdf_com_dev"

But there is an error:

`` (erb):6:in `template': undefined local variable or method `app_name' for #<Refinery::RefineryGenerator:0x00000008dfb0d0> (NameError) ``

How to pls get it inside of my rake task pls?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539148/how-do-i-access-the-name-of-the-rails-3-application-object

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
Rails.application.class.parent_name.downcase
```

I suppose you don't actually have to downcase since your app name is all lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

`Rails.application.engine_name.gsub(/_application/,'')`

is working solution.